# Create View Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Write SQL query to create a view `FAMILY`, containing `TENANT_SS`, `TENANT_NAME`, names of the family members (`NAME`). For those tenants that do not have family members listed in `TENANT_FAMILY`, display `null`. Can I know what are problems?

```
CREATE VIEW FAMILY_VIEW
AS(SELECT T. TENANT_SS, T. TENANT_NAME, TF.NAME
FROM TENANT T, TENANT_FAMILY TF
WHERE T. TENANT_SS  = TF.TENANT_SS;)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There should be no space after the "dot" separator (.) between table names/aliases and column names. For example, `T. TENANT_SS` will not work, that should be `T.TENANT_SS`.

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary parens.  In addition, you have a comma in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW FAMILY_VIEW AS
    SELECT T.TENANT_SS, T.TENANT_NAME, TF.NAME
    FROM TENANT T JOIN
         TENANT_FAMILY TF
         ON T.TENANT_SS  = TF.TENANT_SS;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again.

Comment: However, this query is showing the tenant who has a family. How do I make them to show a tenant who has no family?

Comment: @user6843920 . . . You would use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.  That is one reason why you want to always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.